# How to emulate multi-column layout in pure CSS2?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, multiple-columns

Basically I want to make text "flow" from one column to another in a single container element and make it **without** CSS3/JS.
Here is an example how it should looks like. It shouldn't be exactly a single element, it just need to contain whole text at once.

```css
.container {
  -moz-column-width: 20em;
  -moz-columns: 20em;
  -webkit-columns: 20em;
  columns: 20em;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Lorem ...</div>
```

or

```css
.container {
    column-count: 3;
    column-width: 30%;
    column-gap: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Lorem ...</div>
```

Codepen
https://codepen.io/Apxa/pen/yzgOpv
https://codepen.io/Apxa/pen/yzgJmL

Comment: So what is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Wanna make it work in old IE

Comment: You should mention this in your question, anyway it works in IE11  as well.

Comment: I’m afraid that functionality isn’t possible in IE9- without using JS
http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn I would suggest using Modernizr and adding fallback styles for old IE, setting a max-width and centering for better readability.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply impossible. CSS 2 has no way to do that.

This is why it is being added in the CSS Multi-column Layout Module any why people used JavaScript to achieve that effect in the past.

The closest you can get is to manually create the columns, but picking a point for the text to move to the next column and putting the two blocks of text in different elements (which can be laid out with floating or any other pre-flexbox technique for putting blocks side by side). Differences between font size, column width, etc makes this impractical.

Comment: I know it's possible because this was the question in one of the job interview

Comment: Either (1) They were wrong (2) You misunderstood their requirements (3) You didn't explain their requirements properly here or (4) It was a test to see how you reacted to an impossible set of requirements

Comment: It was a simple question - "How to make it without CSS3?" following discussion about "Multi-column Layout specification".

Comment: Then the answer is JavaScript (which you ruled out in the initial question).

Comment: No js either, it was mentioned as well

Comment: Then see my earlier comment. It is still impossible.